# Retrieve information about cassandra cluster datacenters using datastax driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I need to retrieve information about cluster's datacenters with their nodes. I need to do that using datastax java driver. So I can **not** invoke say "`nodetool status`" and parse its output.

I have tried to query `system.peers` table (`SELECT peer,data_center FROM system.peers`), but it doesn't return me actual information about all peers and datacenters. It contains only partial list of nodes belonging to one of the datacenters.

Is any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for [Metadata](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html) class. `getAllHosts()` returns a Set and each Host contains all the info about that host, including dc.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I was tended to accept your answer, but it doesn't properly work. Anyway I have upvoted it because you gave me a proper way how to do that. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579671/1479414

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@Horia [has given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578586/1479414) me a good hint how to properly resolve this issue. In fact 
[`Metadata.getAllHosts()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getAllHosts--) method returns not a full list of hosts. It returns information only about `N` hosts, where `N` is equal to the replication factor. So it not necessary contains hosts from multiple datacenters.

But using this class I found another way to do that. [`Metadata.getKeyspace(...)`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getKeyspace-java.lang.String-) method returns a `KeyspaceMetadata` object which does contain information about all datacenters:

```
Cluster cluster = ...
Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
Map<String, String> replication = metadata.getKeyspace("keyspace_name").getReplication();
```

Comment: getAllHosts is supposed to return all hosts.  If it isn't I think that would be a bug.  Is it returning all hosts from your local datacenter, or is it only returning a subset of those?  I would expect it to return all hosts in all dcs.

Comment: I see from your other question that its possible this was happening because your DCs were not considering themselves as part of the same cluster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586726/discover-nodes-from-another-datacenter.  Was that ultimately that problem and if by fixing that does getAllHosts now return the right info?

Comment: @AndyTolbert how to fix that? Even is I specify two nodes for a cluster, it still returns me random list of hosts and always less than I expect. That's very weird and irritating. It works only if I specify a particular node of the particular DC. Then it returns hosts from this DC.

Comment: The solution to the other question (having at least 1 host from each DC in seed list) should fix this problem.  The driver uses the system.peers table to resolve your cluster's hosts.  If there is anything missing from getAllHosts, it suggests your peers table doesn't have a complete representation of what you want your cluster to be, so that suggests a misconfiguration of your cluster.

Comment: @AndyTolbert I've checked it with cqlsh and consistency level ALL - it still shows me just a few peers, not a full list. I have no idea what the reason. It might it's just a bug

Comment: @AndyTolbert Furthermore. If I connect with cqlsh to a particular node from,say dc2, I see another list of peers in system.peers, belonging to dc2. So basically consistency level has no impact of this results.

Comment: That sounds like you have 2 different clusters

Comment: @AndyTolbert, no, it is one cluster. As a proof: when I create a keyspace with consistency level set to ALL, it is created in all nodes correctly.

Comment: It would be interesting to check. Could you create a cluster with 2 DC's with 3 nodes in each, with different racks on each. And test what peers table contains under these circumstances

Comment: Here's an example showing a 6 node, 3 DC cluster: https://gist.github.com/tolbertam/94dbe0133031fc4aa07f3981b722e2cc.  getAllHosts returns hosts from all DCs.

Comment: Hm... I am using docker, so it creates 6 containers with each node in it. It might be an important detail: cluster allows SSL connection only